# How to set contentMode when using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I use SDWebImage, here I meet a problem.
I have a ABCButton subclass of UIButton.

```
@interface ABCButton : UIButton
@property (weak, nonatomic) SAIBanner *banner;
@end
@implementation ABCButton
- (void)setBanner:(SAIBanner *)banner {
    _banner = banner;
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:banner.bannerPicUrl] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"default_banner"]];
}
@end
```

I found the `setContentMode` won't work, my question is how to set `contentMode` of `UIButton` or `UIImageView`, when using SDWebImage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contentMode` is a property from the `UIView` class. So you can find it in all its subclasses (`UIButton`, `UIImageView`...) You want specify how should be adjusted the image so you have to set the `contentMode` in the button `UIImageView` property. As a mention before, the button has a `contentMode` property inherited from `UIView`but isn't the property you need set.

So you should change:

```
self.contentMode
```

by

```
[self imageView].contentMode
```

Here the complete code:

```
@interface ABCButton : UIButton
@property (weak, nonatomic) SAIBanner *banner;
@end
@implementation ABCButton
- (void)setBanner:(SAIBanner *)banner {
    _banner = banner;
    [self imageView].contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:banner.bannerPicUrl] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"default_banner"]];
}
@end
```